# ¿por que no se hereda el estilo CSS cuando es llamado en 2 archivos HTML diferentes?

Tags: css

Soy algo nuevo usando esta herramienta y deseaba hacer una pregunta sobre herencia de estilo con `CSS`,tengo mi página principal que se visualiza así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el mismo proyecto creo otro archivo `HTML` y copio el mismo código de la página principal con la diferencia en el nombre del archivo, un archivo se llama `index-copia.html` y el otro se llama `pacas.html` pero los dos poseen exactamente el mismo código y hacen referencia al mismo archivo `CSS`, pero el archivo llamado `pacas.html` se visualiza así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se distorsiona, cambia el tamaño de letras, tamaño y espacio entre imágenes de la bandera y logo y todo lo demás. ¿Por qué sucede eso si están heredando los 2 archivos el mismo estilo?

En otras ocasiones, copié el archivo principal llamado `index-copia.html` en una nueva carpeta con su respectivo estilo y se distorsiona, pareciera que solo el primer archivo creado toma el estilo, los demás archivos que heredan o intentan heredar el estilo se visualizan distorsionados.

¿Puede alguien darme una idea de por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Intenta Inspeccionar la página con (click derecha -> inspeccionar elemento) para ver si se está cargando todo correctamente. Si no lo consigues, sube los archivos a un ftp para que lo podamos mirar.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, se necesita que nos muestres un ejemplo (una foto no es un ejemplo) del problema para que podamos ayudarte a encontrar la respuesta.

Comment: Hola @Alejandro. Provee el código HTML/CSS y todo lo que sea necesario para reproducir tu problema y podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ¿Ambos HTML estan en la misma carpeta? Quizá la referencia al CSS cambió si se encuentran en carpetas diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

Umm! Yo diría que no es por el CSS, sino que el navegador te está guardando el nivel de zoom que tenías. Dale a la opción de reiniciar zoom del navegador (CTRL-0) en ambas páginas. También puedes impedir el zoom añadiendo opciones en una etiqueta meta para `viewport`, aunque iría en contra de un diseño fluido.

Comment: muchisimas gracias!! era eso del estandar del zoom una pagina me tomaba por 75% y la otra 100% que ingenuo descuido al no fijarme en algo asi muchas gracias

Comment: Y ¿cómo se explica que el zoom cambie el color el título "Bienvenidos al sitio oficial de..." ?

Comment: Tendría que mirar el código, pero casi te podría asegurar que es el cambio de color para distinguir los *"enlaces visitados"* .